# Create a URL based on the post URL that can open the WordPress editor directly?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to create a URL based on the post URL so that it can open the WordPress editor directly?

For example, for https://www.example.com/mypost/, use a URL https://www.example.com/mypost/?action=edit to open the editor directly?

Currently in WordPress, when editing a post, the URL format looks like below:

```
https://www.example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=12345&action=edit
```

Can I pass the post slug or URL as the parameter instead of a post ID, like below:

```
https://www.example.com/wp-admin/post.php?posturl="/mypost/"&action=edit
```

Where can I find the document on this?

Comment: how and where are you to generating the the URL?

Comment: _Why_ would you need to pass anything other than the post ID? _"Where can I find the document on this?"_ - not sure if there is anything explicitly on this topic. This is backend functionality, so it should not need "pretty" URLs. The function `edit_post_link` exists, so you should not have to create such links yourself, as long as you have a post id or post object available, this will create the correct link for you automatically.

Comment: @CBroe, I want to batch create multiple editable URLs

Comment: And what is stopping you from using `edit_post_link` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can look into the source of post.php: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/post.php
On line 19-27 you can see that post.php only accepts post id's, otherwise it sets the post id 0